# AS3: How to detect collisions?

Tags: actionscript-3, collections, box2d

I'm trying to make a simple game, when the ball falls into certain block, you win.

**Mechanics:** The ball falls through several obstacles, in the end there are two blocks, if the ball touches the left block you win, the next level will contain more blocks and less space between them.

**Test the movie** (click on the screen to drop the ball):
http://gabrielmeono.com/downloads/Lucky_Hit_Alpha.swf

**These are the main variables:**

```
    var winBox:QuickObject;//You win
    var looseBox:QuickObject;//You loose
    var gameBall:QuickObject;//Ball dropped
```

**Question:**

- How do I detect a collision and make a function if the ball hits the winBox? (Win message/Next level)*

Thanks, here is the full code:

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width = 600, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

    public class LuckyHit extends MovieClip {

        public var sim:QuickBox2D;
        var winBox:QuickObject;
        var looseBox:QuickObject;
        var gameBall:QuickObject;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function LuckyHit()
        {
            sim = new QuickBox2D(this);  
            //sim.createStageWalls();
            winBox = sim.addBox({x:5,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});
            looseBox = sim.addBox({x:15,y:600/30, width:300/30, height:10/30, density:0});


            // make obstacles
            for (var i:int = 0; i<(stage.stageWidth/50); i++){ 
            //End
                 sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:16, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:2 + i * 1.5, y:15, radius:0.1, density:0});

            //Mid End

                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:14, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:13, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:12, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:11, radius:0.1, density:0});
                  sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 2, y:10, radius:0.1, density:0});


            //Middle Start
                 sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:09, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:08, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:0 + i * 1.5, y:07, radius:0.1, density:0});
                 sim.addCircle({x:1 + i * 1.5, y:06, radius:0.1, density:0});

            }

            sim.start();


            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        }

        /**
         * ..
         * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
         */

        private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            gameBall = sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(1), radius:0.25, density:5});


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless I misread as I am not familiar with box2d, you should use [hitTestObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject()), when it returns true then call whatever function you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: Added second argument gameBall.

I'm not familiar with QuickBox2D, but give this a shot.

```
var simContacts:QuickContacts;

public function LuckyHit()
{
    ...
    simContacts = sim.addContactListener();
    simContacts.addEventListener(QuickContacts.ADD, contactListener);
}

...

private function contactListener(event:Event)
{
    if (simContacts.isCurrentContact(winBox, gameBall))
    {
        // They won.
    }
}
```

The relevant class in the [QuickBox2D documentation](http://actionsnippet.com/qb2d/docs/html/index.html) is **QuickContacts**.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries available that can handle collision detection. A simple Google search should return quite a few.

In the meantime, you can always check this [article](http://www.anotherearlymorning.com/2009/07/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-in-actionscript-3/)

Answer (score 0):

A circle and a rectangle is colliding if bounding boxes of both objects overlap and bounding circles of both objects overlap.

But like Gabriel said, you'll be better off using some existing library, rather than writing your own, unless you really want to understand the mechanics behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Flixel is a good library for beginning game making, and collision detection is a core feature.

Unless this is a class assignment that doesn't allow outside libraries?